how to Disable Button in the table after ajax?
Each row in the table has a button. When the button is clicked, it will turn blue and become unclickable.
I have try to use it ,but cannot work
  $(this).parent().attr('data-id').prop('disabled', true)

but  only the button in the first row can be disabled, the other buttons in rows cannot be clicked. Is there any mistake in that?
part of my code as below,
<button type='button' id='mybutton'>Click Me</button>
 <div id="mydiv"></div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">IP</th>
        <th scope="col">action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

  <tbody id="userlist">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>2024-06-17 15:23:52</td>
      <td>10.10.10.1</td>
      <td data-id="666fe488a202ef5275f21378"> <button id = 'disable' class="del btn btn-primary">Disable</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>2024-06-27 16:12:36</td>
      <td>10.10.10.2</td>
      <td data-id="667d1ef595c11234567c738b"> <button id = 'disable' class="del btn btn-primary ">Disable</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <th scope="row">3</th>
  <td>2024-07-27 16:12:36</td>
  <td>10.10.10.3</td>
  <td data-id="667d1ef595c1baeb085c1234"> <button id = 'disable' class="del btn btn-primary ">Disable</button></td>
</tr>

javascript ,
$('#disable').click( function() {
$('#disable').prop('disabled',true).css('opacity',0.5);
});

$('#mybutton').click( function() {
   $('#mybutton').prop('disabled',true).css('opacity',0.5);
 });


A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, please do not send us to external platforms.
